# Error running awk program in command line: "^ backslash not last character on line"

Tags: awk, visual-studio-code

Following the manual gawk
https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html

I'm writing the first example in visual studio code using awk extension:

```
awk 'BEGIN { print "Don\47t Panic!" }'
```

and the console are returning me this error:

> ^ backslash not last character on line

What could be the problem?

Comment: Yes, i think.I´ve been using visual studio code with awk extension. I was following this tutorial before: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/awk-command-unixlinux-examples/    and the scipts there runs well.

Comment: Oh, then you should have mentioned that in your question.

Comment: That´s right thanks.

Comment: This is probably a quotation issue btw. Look up how you should quote arguments on VS Code shell

Comment: My understanding is that single quotes in CMD.EXE are just plain characters. You might need outer double quotes, and have to escape the inner quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be a bug with your version of awk or some way that vscode might parse `\47`?  For me... direct from Linux command line, there is no issue.

```
$ awk -V
GNU Awk 4.2.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.1.2)
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2018 Free Software Foundation.

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation; either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program. If not, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.

$ awk 'BEGIN { print "Don\47t Panic!" }'
Don't Panic!
```